# Minimum access levels to run MySql stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to setup my .NET 4.7.1 program that is connecting to a MySQL database 8.0 to use the minimum privileges to run.
The .NET program is using MySql.Data to make connection. The minimum right for a user to execute a stored procedure is typically only **EXECUTE** privilege. This works fine from MySQL workbench or command line.

Upon running the .NET program this does return the following exception:
**System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'**

To make it easy, I have create a very small demo program to demonstrate the issue.

Setup of the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE Spike;

CREATE PROCEDURE TestAccess()
BEGIN
END;

CREATE USER Spike@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'sample';

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `TestAccess` TO Spike@localhost;
```

Setup program code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Spike;uid=Spike;pwd=sample"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection open");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "TestAccess";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Query executed");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The crash happens at the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
The stack from the crash is interesting, since it seems to indicate that the information_schema is queried. When logging all statements I can see that the last statement before the exception is:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines WHERE 1=1 AND routine_schema LIKE 'Spike' AND routine_name LIKE 'TestAccess'
```

I cannot grant different rights on information_schema, but I could give more rights on the stored procedure to make more information visible in the routines table, this feels wrong however. Simple tests with granting CREATE and ALTER access also did not work.

Is there something else I can do, without granting too much privileges?

Comment: Upon further investigation it seems that only the ROUTINE_DEFINITION column is null in this scenario, while when using root to look at the information_schema then this column is filled.

Comment: Maybe related: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Connector/NET, similar to [bug 75301](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75301) but a little different. When it's trying to determine parameter metadata for the procedure, it first creates a `MySqlSchemaCollection` named `Procedures` with *all* metadata about the procedure. (This is the `SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines WHERE 1=1 AND routine_schema LIKE 'Spike' AND routine_name LIKE 'TestAccess'` query you see in your log.)

The `Spike` user account doesn't have permission to read the `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` column, so it is `NULL`. Connector/NET expects this field to be non-NULL and throws a `SqlNullValueException` exception trying to read it.

There are two workarounds:

1) The first, which you've discovered, is to set `CheckParameters=False` in your connection string. This will disable retrieval of stored procedure metadata (avoiding the crash), but may lead to harder-to-debug problems calling other stored procedures if you don't get the order and type of parameters exactly right. (Connector/NET can no longer map them for you using the metadata.)

2) Switch to a different ADO.NET MySQL library that doesn't have this bug: [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/). It's highly compatible with Connector/NET, performs faster, and fixes a lot of [known issues](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs).

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer with which I am quite pleased. It is changing the connection string by adding **CheckParameters=false**:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Spike;uid=Spike;pwd=sample;CheckParameters=false"))
```

This disables parameter checking, and thereby information_schema queries.