# .NET Dapper/MySql 8.0 issue: Only root user is able to execute stored procedure. Other users get SqlNullValueException

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have a small chunk of code which executes a stored procedure in a mysql database:

```
        string connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;database=myDb;pwd=mypwd;";

        using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var record = db.Query<dynamic>("record_Get", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
```

When the connection string uses root user credentials, the stored procedure executes as expected. When I try to use a different set of credentials however (other_user), I get the following error message when querying the database:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'
```

I have tried to ensure that other_user has the correct permissions. I have gone to the Users and Privilieges tab and granted SELECT and EXECUTE permissions at a schema level. For good measure, I also ran:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON mydb.* TO 'other_user'@'%';
```

No dice.

If I swap the record_Get stored procedure query in my C# code for a direct SQL command the record is returned successfully:

```
var record = db.Query<dynamic>("SELECT * from record"); // Not the actual query
```

The user is also able to execute the Stored Procedure within a SQL script:

```
EXECUTE record_Get(); /* works fine! */
```

Trying to execute the stored procedure by clicking on the lightning symbol in the Workbench GUI does nothing at all. The procedures are listed and the user can execute them through a script, but the GUI button does nothing. (Not sure if that's connected)

It seems likely to be a permissions issue but I've not seen this before and I'm not too sure on where to look next. Does anyone have any suggestions?

mysql version: 8.0.12

Comment: Try `GRANT EXECUTE ON mydb.record_Get TO 'other_user'@'%';` - MySQL tends to be very finicky around permissions.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately still getting the same issue.

I have confirmed it's a permissions issue by temporarily granting other_user the DBA administrative role. This resolved the issue, but I'm still in the dark on exactly which permission other_user is lacking

Comment: You'll likely need `SELECT` permission to `information_schema.routines`; see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343425/23633

Comment: Thanks Bradley, I slotted your package into my project and everything is now working correctly. Really appreciate the help!